# IBM Cloud Classic Infrastructure Single Server Firewall has No Rules and Error when Attempting to Add Rule

Tags: ibm-cloud

I could log a support ticket but the suggested procedure from IBM Docs is to ask questions here first.

I have just provisioned 2 virtual machines with single server firewalls.

In the documentation at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/hardware-firewall-shared?topic=hardware-firewall-shared-configuring-the-hardware-firewall-shared-  there is a statement "When a firewall is first added to a server, a set of rules is initially put in place that allows all traffic to reach the server. The rules can then be edited to control the traffic reaching the server.".

However, there are no rules displayed.

Trying to Add a Rule, e.g. open port 80 for http. I specify the public IP address along with the apparent CIDR /28 but I get an error message stating:

The destination 'X.X.X.X/28' must be within protectable destination subnets for IPv4 rule '1'
Try again or contact support if the problem persists.

Where X.X.X.X is the network address of my (apparent) subnet and not the public IP address of the virtual server.

Any pointers please.....

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0):

As commonly occurs, no sooner do I post my question, than a 'penny drops' and I kind of figure out my own answer.

I had also provisioned this server with 4 secondary IP addresses. That is apparently accomplished within IBM Cloud by routing the secondary public IP addresses to the primary public IP address. In turn, this modifies the recognised subnet information from the primary to the secondary.

Adding a new firewall rule for one of the secondary IP addresses works without an error.

Hopefully this will enlighten someone else.

cheers
Tony